# How to concatenate NSArray values by excluding brackets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

My array is like this

```
(1,2,3,)
(4,5,6,)
(7,8,9,)
```

I want to concatenate all these values i.e;123456789

I tried like this `NSString *str5=[array componentsJoinedByString:@" "];`

but I'm not getting the output.

can anyone provide me some information.

Comment: Could you Paste the code for adding the values to your array? because The array doesn't store the objects like that

Comment: That is not an accurate description of your arrays.  What objects are contained in the arrays?

Comment: What output are you getting ? The objects in the array, are they instances of NSString or NSNumber ? Your array seems to contain 3 other arrays ? Is that the case ?

Comment: can you explain it clearly so that I can help you because array doesn't store the objects in the above mentioned format

Comment: @Sunny Please understand that this kind of nagging is not welcome on SO. Sahara Pune will see your post and decide on his own if it helps in his case or not.

Comment: @nikolia Ruhe:ok frnd thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have an `NSArray` of `NSArray`. First loop through the original `NSArray` and flatten it then apply `componentsJoinedByString`.

Create an `NSMutableArray`, loop through your original array and call `addObjectsFromArray:` with each subarray.

```
NSMutableArray *flattenArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSArray *array in originalArray)
{
    [flattenArray addObjectsFromArray: array];
}

NSString *str5 = [flattenArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

try like this it'l give expected output but i don't know is it efficient method or not ,

```
NSArray *arr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"(1,2,3)",@"(4,5,6)", nil];
    NSString *str=[arr componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",()"];
    str = [[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Character replacing brackets with null values.

Code ::

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"(1, 2, 3, )", @"(4, 5, 6, )", @"(7, 8, 9, )", nil];

for (int i = 0; i < [arr count]; i++) {
    NSLog (@"==> %@", [or objectAtIndex:i]);
}

NSString *str5 = [arr componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@" ==> %@", str5);

str5 = [str5 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
str5 = [str5 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
str5 = [str5 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
str5 = [str5 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];

//Or Try this
NSCharacterSet *doNotWantChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",() "];
str5 = [[str5 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWantChars] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
NSLog(@" ==> %@", str5);

NSLog(@"Output :: %@", str5);
```

I've replaced **"(", ")", " "** & **","** with **""**(null) values

Hopefully, it'll help you.
Thanks.